# How to manage a Managed Metadata site column which allow multiple selection for large document library (since we can not index it)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search, managed-property, crawled-property

We have created a document library inside our SharePoint online site to manage our customer documents >> and we added a site Column of type Managed Metadata to tag the documents with the related customer/s.

Each document will be tagged to either specific customer/s or to All (we currently have 250 customers), as follow:-

[image]

now the problem is that the document library will contain millions of documents and we need to index the Managed Metadata site column, but since this Managed Metadata site column allow multiple sections so it can not be indexed. so in this case how we can link a document with multiple customers ?

**One solution** but not sure if it will work, is to create for example 10 site columns which are linked to the customer term store >> and each site column allow single selection (so we can index them) >> so we will have 10 crawl properties >> then we can create one managed property which contains the 10 crawl properties >> so users can filer the document library using the manged property inside the PnP Modern search web part >> and the managed property will cover the 10 crawl properties.. will this work? or there is a better solution to our issue?

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft documentation suggests managed metadata columns can be indexed: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0 are you experiencing an error when attempting to index the column?

Comment: @CallumCrowley they can not be indexed incase they allow multiple selection

Comment: My tenant allows me to index a managed metadata column, which is inline with Microsoft documentation which says you can do this.

Comment: @CallumCrowley and does this managed metadata allow multiple selection, as in my case if the managed metadata does allow multiple selection the column will not appear inside the Index list

Comment: I see, seems to have been missed from their documentation if that's the case. I would recommend looking in to using search for large libraries etc

Comment: @CallumCrowley ok using search for large lists will not work for un-indexed columns

Comment: It will, the search service indexes everything. It's separate from the list column indexing functionality.